# Boost::graph undefined properties

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am loading a graphviz dot diagram into a Boost::Graph object.  I want to make sure that the nodes and arcs have a set of specific properties but do not care if they have any other properties.  All I want Boost::Graph to do is to flag those (a catchable exception is fine) and not just abort the loading of the file.

For example, I would like the following two nodes to parse into a vertex structure that contains only "style" and "fillcolor" and ignored any "unknown_tag" tags.

```
0 [style=filled, fillcolor="Green"]
1 [style=filled, fillcolor="Green", unknown_tag="fubar"]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graphviz loader puts properties that are not in your `dynamic_properties` list into a separate structure, so they should be ignored just as you want.